# What is the right way to check if a type hint is annotated?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Python 3.9 introduces the `Annotated` class which allows adding arbitrary metadata to type hints, e.g.,

```
class A:
    x: Annotated[int, "this is x"]
```

The annotated type hint can be obtained by setting the new `include_extras` argument of `get_type_hints`:

```
>>> get_type_hints(A, include_extras=True)
{'x': typing.Annotated[int, 'this is x']}
```

And the metadata itself can be accessed through the `__metadata__` attribute of the type hint.

```
>>> h = get_type_hints(A, include_extras=True)
>>> h["x"].__metadata__
('this is x',)
```

But, my question is, what is the right way to test if a type hint even *is* `Annotated`? That is, something akin to:

```
if IS_ANNOTATED(h["x"]):
    # do something with the metadata
```

As far as I can tell, there is no documented method to do so, and there are a couple possible ways, none of which seem ideal.

Comparing the `type` to `Annotated` doesn't work because the type hint is not an instance of `Annotated`:

```
>>> type(h["x"])
typing._AnnotatedAlias
```

So we have to do:

```
if type(h["x"]) is _AnnotatedAlias:
    ...
```

But, given the leading underscore in `_AnnotatedAlias`, this requires using, presumably, an implementation detail.

The other option is to directly check for the `__metadata__` attribute:

```
if hasattr(h["x"], "__metadata__"):
    ...
```

But this assumes that the `__metadata__` attribute is unique to `Annotated`, which can't necessarily be assumed when dealing with user-defined type hints too.

So, is there perhaps a better way to do this test?

Comment: I'm struggling with a problem similar to this at the moment — I don't have an answer for you, as I haven't been able to come up with anything better than your suggestions. I believe the reason that there is no official way to perform this kind of test at the moment is that the typing module is still new and changing rapidly in each python version, so the API can't be guaranteed to stay the same from version to version.

Comment: Generally you would use duck typing for this. So instead of explicitly checking, you'd simply use a try/except block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
from typing import Annotated, Any
annot_type = type(Annotated[int, 'spam'])


def is_annotated(hint: Any, annot_type=annot_type) -> bool:
    return (type(hint) is annot_type) and hasattr(hint, '__metadata__')
```

Or, using the newish [PEP 647](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/):

```
from typing import Annotated, TypeGuard, Any
annot_type = type(Annotated[int, 'spam'])


def is_annotated(hint: Any, annot_type=annot_type) -> TypeGuard[annot_type]:
    return (type(hint) is annot_type) and hasattr(hint, '__metadata__')
```

This solution sidesteps having to use any implementation details directly. I included the extra `hasattr(hint, '__metadata__')` test in there just for safety.

##### Discussion of this solution

Interestingly, this solution seems to be pretty similar to the way Python currently implements several functions in the `inspect` module. The current implementation of [`inspect.isfunction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/366fcbac18e3adc41e3901580dbedb6a91e41a10/Lib/inspect.py#L277) is as follows:

```
# inspect.py

# -- snip --

import types

# -- snip --

def isfunction(object):
    """Return true if the object is a user-defined function.
    Function objects provide these attributes:
        __doc__         documentation string
        __name__        name with which this function was defined
        __code__        code object containing compiled function bytecode
        __defaults__    tuple of any default values for arguments
        __globals__     global namespace in which this function was defined
        __annotations__ dict of parameter annotations
        __kwdefaults__  dict of keyword only parameters with defaults"""
    return isinstance(object, types.FunctionType)
```

So then you go to the [`types`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/366fcbac18e3adc41e3901580dbedb6a91e41a10/Lib/types.py) module to find out the definition of `FunctionType`, and you find it is defined like so:

```
# types.py

"""
Define names for built-in types that aren't directly accessible as a builtin.
"""

# -- snip --

def _f(): pass
FunctionType = type(_f)
```

Because, of course, the exact nature of a `function` object is dependent on implementation details of Python at the C level.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with `typing.get_origin` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin):

```py
assert typing.get_origin(Annotated[int, 0]) is Annotated

assert typing.get_args(Annotated[int, 0]) == (int, 0)
```

Comment: You need to make sure you  also import `get_origin` and `get_args` from `typing_extensions` instead of `typing` for python version < 3.9.